# Keeping track of multiple select box items

Tags: angularjs

I have the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/Qgmz7/119/

I am trying to keep track of what is selected and what is not, how do I go about doing this?

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="cCtrl">
        <select multiple ng-model="campaign" ng-options="c.ID as c.Name for c in campaigns">
            <option ng-selected="c.Selected" value="">-- choose campaign --</option>
        </select>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in campaigns">{{item.Name}} - {{item.Selected}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

function cCtrl($scope) {    
    $scope.campaigns = [
        {Selected:true, ID: 1, Name:"James"},
        {Selected:false, ID: 2, Name:"James"},
        {Selected:true, ID: 3, Name:"James"},
    ];
}
```

Comment: change **c.id** to **c.ID** in  **ng-options="c.id as c.Name for c in campaigns"**

Comment: Unfortuantely still does not keep the objects updated. I updated the fiddle for you

Comment: Check my [example](https://jsfiddle.net/tkgxnjwy/). I know that it's not a better solution, and it require to be improved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi try this http://jsfiddle.net/a63k106s/

```
function cCtrl($scope) {  
    $scope.campaigns = [
        {Selected:true, ID: 4, Name:"James"},
        {Selected:false, ID: 2, Name:"James"},
        {Selected:true, ID: 3, Name:"James"},
    ];

    $scope.$watch('campaign', function (nowSelected) {          
        angular.forEach($scope.campaigns, function(campaign) {
            campaign.Selected = nowSelected.indexOf(campaign.ID) >= 0
        });
    });
}
```